# Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR with firebase google sign in with react native even i have used sha 1 key in project fingur print and use web client id in conf

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I created a project in react native in which i linked the Firebase with it and enabled email password auth it is working but google sign is giving developer error when i choose the google account. I even use the same sha 1 key and web client id. I create Firebase objects in android mode. I tried everything from the internet but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

you can add @react-native-google-signin/google-signin and @react-native-firebase/auth

above this two plugin you can used

i.e

```
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
        
        GoogleSignin.configure({
          webClientId: '<Your webCLientId>',
        });
```

And another example

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
    
    async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
      // Check if your device supports Google Play
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });
      // Get the users ID token
      const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    
      // Create a Google credential with the token
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    
      // Sign-in the user with the credential
      return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    }
```

hope it's working fine for you.

And you also prefer this link also :- https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth